# Get local time from different Timezone using batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I do not want to use any scripting language, but just plain command line commands/scripting.

I can solve this using a (prepared) TZ table (e.g. format: UTC+06:00 + 'TZ name'), then use TZUTIL to collect their resp UTC values and calculate the Timezone's local time (preferably taking DST into account).

I am just hoping that somebody already did this in a more "proper" way. Searched this/other sites, but found nothing so far.

ps: no 'external' tools/etc, since the final batch-file needs to be distributed EMEA-wise.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more what would be "proper" while not adding any extra layer?

Comment: You might be interested in the `wmic` command which can return the local date/time in a locale-independent manner; for instance: `wmic os get LocalDateTime`; I'm pretty sure there is a way to get the date/time in the format you need...

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense - Windows batch is a primitive scripting language, so how can you claim you do not want to use any scripting language?. And what is EMEA distribution? Keeping a catalog of DST rules is tricky, given that they change over time, and the rules are not necessarily consistent within a country (for example, not all locations within the US use DST).

Comment: First some clarification: no extra layer = nothing but pure DOS scripting (so no PHP, java, etc). And EMEA=Europe-MiddleEast-Africa (~regional division)  -  That said: I did look into WMIC for this purpose, but this can only get me the local time. But then #Paul (ok?) got me thinking: I get the user's actual local time, switch to the different TZ (using tzutil); get local time again, then switch back to the user's local time. Switching between different TZs is practically unnoticeable by the user (pretty much instant). And I should now have both/correct time info. Keep you posted...

Comment: Confirmed working (as i explained above by switching between TZs). Thx @Paul for pointing my nose in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

1. get the local date and time (`wmic`)
2. get the local offset (`wmic`)
3. convert the local time to UTC with the help of #2
4. get the offset of a TZ. (`tzutil /l`)
5. convert the result of #3 and #4 not to mention the change of date (this is where it gets complicated).

I think I have not forgotten something? :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a need to obtain time zone information in a specific format from MS Windows systems via a batch file.  I could not find what I needed so I developed my own.  Thought I would share for others to use.  Use the code and adjust as necessary.

```
@echo off
REM Obtain the ActiveBias value and convert to decimal
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation /v ActiveTimeBias ^| grep -i "ActiveTimeBias"') do set /a abias=%%a
for /f "tokens=3-8" %%n in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation /v TimeZoneKeyName') do set tzn=%%n %%o %%p %%q %%r 2>NUL

REM Set the + or - sign variable to reflect the timezone offset
IF "%abias:~0,1%"=="-" (set si=+) ELSE (set si=-)
for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%t in ('echo %abias%') do set tzc=%%t

REM Calculate to obtain floating points (decimal values)
set /a tzd=100*%tzc%/60

REM Calculate the active bias to obtain the hour
set /a tze=%tzc%/60

REM Set the minutes based on the result of the floating point calculation
IF "%tzd%"=="0" (set en=00 && set si=)
IF "%tzd:~1%"=="00" (set en=00) ELSE IF "%tzd:~2%"=="00" (set en=00 && set tz=%tzd:~0,2%)
IF "%tzd:~1%"=="50" (set en=30) ELSE IF "%tzd:~2%"=="50" (set en=30 && set tz=%tzd:~0,2%)
IF "%tzd:~1%"=="75" (set en=45) ELSE IF "%tzd:~2%"=="75" (set en=45 && set tz=%tzd:~0,2%)

REM Adding a 0 to the beginning of a single digit hour value
IF %tze% LSS 10 (set tz=0%tze%)

REM Display timezone name and offset
echo %tzn% %si%%tz%%en%
```